# Change onclick reference inside js function dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic

```html
<html>
<script>
function fn1(event)
{

alert("in fn1"+event.id);
}

function fn2(event)
{

alert(event.id);
}

function fnChange(event)
{
 alert(event.id +"  "+event.name);
 event.onclick=fn1;
//without passing parameter ,the code works.I dono how to change the reference to fn1 along with the variable passed
 

}
</script>
<body>
<button id="b1" name="b1Name" onclick="fnChange(this);">The time is?</button>


</body>

</html>
```

I want after calling fnChange , every click to the button should call fn1 along with the buttonReference passed as parameter.

Thanks and Regards,
Shiva RV

Answer (score 0):

Just use a closure(e.g. boolean `firstClickDone`) to detect if first click already was done

```
<html>
<script>

var firstClickDone = false;

function fn1(event)
{

alert("in fn1"+event.id);
}

function fn2(event)
{

alert(event.id);
}

function fnChange(event)
{

 if(firstClickDone){
   fn1(event);
 }
 else{
   alert(event.id +"  "+event.name);
   firstClickDone = true;
 }

}
</script>
<body>
<button id="b1" name="b1Name" onclick="fnChange(this);">The time is?</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello, I want to change the reference. I mean after b1 button is clicked once, It should not call function fnChange , else after it should call function fn1.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code, you can store the event ID in a variable and pass the parameter to get your value for the event :

```html
<script>
function fn1(event)
{

alert("in fn1"+event);
}

function fn2(event)
{

alert(event.id);
}

function fnChange(event)
{
 alert(event.id +"  "+event.name);
 var temp=(event.id +"  "+event.name);
fn1(temp);
//without passing parameter ,the code works.I dono how to change the reference to fn1 along with the variable passed
 

}
</script>
<body>
<button id="b1" name="b1Name" onclick="fnChange(this);">The time is?</button>


</body>
```

Comment: Hello, I want to change the reference. I mean after b1 button is clicked once, It should not call function fnChange , else after it should call function fn1